# Simplifying Jquery code HELP!

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog, simplify

I am trying to load two modal dialog boxes with Jquery. Both of them load separate pages using ajax. The only problem is that only one of them works.

I think I need to simplify my code but am unsure how.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var dialogOpts = {
      modal: true,
      bgiframe: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 550,
      draggable: true,
      resizeable: true,
      title: "Your campaign rates",
   };
$("#ratesbox").dialog(dialogOpts);   //end dialog

   $('#ratesbutton').click(
      function() {
         $("#ratesbox").load("rate_sheet/index.php", [], function(){
               $("#ratesbox").dialog("open");
            }
         );
         return false;
      }
   );
}); 
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var dialogOptsPass = {
      modal: true,
      bgiframe: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 550,
      draggable: true,
      resizeable: true,
      title: "Change your pasword",
   };
$("#passwordbox").dialog(dialogOptsPass);   //end dialog

   $('#passwordbutton').click(
      function() {
         $("#passwordbox").load("change_password/index.php", [], function(){
               $("#passwordbox").dialog("open");
            }
         );
         return false;
      }
   );
}); 
</script>
```

Is it posible to combine the two scripts????

Comment: I'm so curious who upvotes the question in that form

Comment: @jAndy: Shall we call it vote throttling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your script down a bit, like this:

```
$(function(){
  var dialogOpts = {
        modal: true,
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 550,
        draggable: true,
        resizeable: true,
        title: "Your campaign rates"
     };
  $("#ratesbox, #passwordbox").dialog(dialogOpts);
  $("#passwordbox").dialog("option", "title", "Change your pasword");
  //or...
  //$("#ratesbox").dialog(dialogOpts);
  //$("#passwordbox").dialog($.extend(dialogOpts, { title: "Change your pasword" }));

   $('#ratesbutton').click(function() {
     $("#ratesbox").load("rate_sheet/index.php", function(){
       $("#ratesbox").dialog("open");
     });
     return false;
   });
   $('#passwordbutton').click(function() {
     $("#passwordbox").load("change_password/index.php", function(){
       $("#passwordbox").dialog("open");
     });
     return false;
   });
});
```

...but I didn't see any particular problem with your code (except one that should cause problems for *both*), it's most likely related to your markup as to why one isn't working.  Also make sure to remove trailing commas in object declarations, you currently have `title: "Your campaign rates",`...don't have a dangling comma there, IE in particular will blow a gasket, eat your cat and steal your car.

Comment: +1 IE did that to me too! Except it doesn't have a license, so when it got pulled over, I got the ticket! #%@$$#$!